# Excel Addin and ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, tfs, excel-addins

I want to add functionality with my our website, when you request to change a set of date (Shown in Gridview). that when you click "Edit" that it would open up in Excel.
When that is completed and the user made changes he/she should click on a addin that would post it back to the website and update in the database.

(For example the Team Foundation Server, you can request to open the tasks in Excel and when it saves it would update TFS)

Would this be possible and can anyone redirect me to some examples to do this

Kind Regards:)

Answer (score 0):

TFS achieves this with a plugin that in installed on the computer running excel and handles the update and integration.

The support for Sharepoint is also built into Office OOB.

You would need you would need to create your own plugin for excel and distribute it to your users.